# How to count offcore PMU events on an old kernel?

Tags: profiling, perf, intel-pmu

I want to collect [OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP](https://perfmon-events.intel.com/index.html?pltfrm=cascadelake_server.html&evnt=OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP) event on a cascadelake server. My CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6230R, and my kernel is 4.18.0. I also tried Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5218 with kernel 5.14.0, nothing different.

My perf version is 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.debug

**Attempt 1:** Directly use perf for collection

It is supported in [kernel-5.14](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/cascadelakex/memory.json).

But my kernel version is too old, the corresponding offscore events cannot be directly used by the perf. The output of command *"perf list | grep OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP"* is empty.

update:
perf can recognize this server as skylake, but still can't output events listed in [skylake/memory.json](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/skylake/memory.json)

```
$ cat /sys/devices/cpu/caps/pmu_name
skylake

# perf list | grep offcore
[empty]

# perf list | grep rfo
[empty]
```

**Attempt 2:** Use PCM-raw to collect data

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/intel/pcm/blob/master/doc/PCM_RAW_README.md), but the numbers I collected were all 0.

```
# ./emon -C OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP --dry-run -m
Event Set 0
        OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP (PerfEvtSel0 (0x186) = 0x00000000004301b7)
          CC=ALL PC=0x0 UMASK=0x1 E=0x1 EDGE=0 INT=0x0 INV=0x0 CMASK=0x0 AMT=0x0


# pcm-raw -e core/config=0x00000000004301b7,name=OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP
,,,SKT0CORE0,SKT0CORE1,SKT0CORE2,...
Date,Time,ms,OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP,OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP,OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP,...
2023-10-17,11:49:55.483,1001,0,0,0,... (all zero)
```

Perhaps it is because PCM-raw does not support the collection of offcore events.

> Currently supported PMUs: core, m3upi, upi(ll)/qpi(ll), imc, m2m, pcu, cha/cbo, iio, ubox

**Is there any way to collect corresponding counters?**

*Update Attempt 3:* I tried to update kernel to 5.14, The result is the same as Attempt 1.

Comment: On older perf versions, `ocperf.py` from https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools/ was a useful wrapper to map symbolic event names to raw event command-line args for `perf`.  I forget when it stopped being necessary on my Arch Linux system.

Comment: `perf list | grep OFFCORE` is empty on my system, too, because `perf` uses lower-case names.  There are tons of events with `offcore` in their name on my Skylake-client system (and there have been for years; 5.14 isn't that old).  Use `perf list | less -i` and search interactively with `/`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I searched for "rfo" and "offcore", couldn't find either. My perf version is "3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.debug".

Comment: Lol.  Use a `perf` version that matches your kernel!  `3.10.0` is way older even than your 4.18 kernel.  (Or try ocperf.py; it might help with such an old `perf` version.  But it's probably better to upgrade perf to match the kernel for ABI / API compatibility with kernel internals.)