# Why using non-temporal store instructions cannot reduce memory bandwidth usage? (Writes seem to be generating extra reads)

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, intel, memcpy, memory-bandwidth

I want to use the non-temporary instruction to reduce the read bandwidth generated by write allocate during the memcpy process. The expected read and write bandwidth after optimization should be the same, both equal to the actual data processing bandwidth.

But I found during the experiment that the memory read bandwidth is still 1.7x the write bandwidth.

My code is written using inline assembly, and the core logic is as follows:

```
asm volatile(
        "mov    %[memarea], %%rax \n"   // rax = dst arr
        "mov    %[srcarea], %%rcx \n"   // rcx = src arr
        "1: \n" // start of write loop
        "movdqa 0*16(%%rcx), %%xmm0 \n"
        "movdqa 1*16(%%rcx), %%xmm1 \n"
        "movdqa 2*16(%%rcx), %%xmm2 \n"
        "movdqa 3*16(%%rcx), %%xmm3 \n"
        "movdqa 4*16(%%rcx), %%xmm4 \n"
        "movdqa 5*16(%%rcx), %%xmm5 \n"
        "movdqa 6*16(%%rcx), %%xmm6 \n"
        "movdqa 7*16(%%rcx), %%xmm7 \n"
        "PREFETCHNTA 8*16(%%rcx) \n"
        "PREFETCHNTA 12*16(%%rcx) \n"
        "movntdq %%xmm0, 0*16(%%rax) \n"
        "movntdq %%xmm1, 1*16(%%rax) \n"
        "movntdq %%xmm2, 2*16(%%rax) \n"
        "movntdq %%xmm3, 3*16(%%rax) \n"
        "movntdq %%xmm4, 4*16(%%rax) \n"
        "movntdq %%xmm5, 5*16(%%rax) \n"
        "movntdq %%xmm6, 6*16(%%rax) \n"
        "movntdq %%xmm7, 7*16(%%rax) \n"
        "add    $8*16, %%rax \n"
        "add    $8*16, %%rcx \n"
        // test write loop condition
        "cmp    %[end], %%rax \n"       // compare to end iterator
        "jb     1b \n"
        : 
        : [memarea] "r" (dst), [srcarea] "r" (src), [end] "r" (dst+effect_size)
        : "rax", "rcx", "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4", "xmm5", "xmm6", "xmm7", "cc", "memory");
    
    _mm_sfence();
```

In the memset test, the version based on non-temporary instructions does not generate read bandwidth, so the functionality of the instructions is indeed effective.

Is there anything wrong with my usage?

---

update：

I conducted an experiment with [the code provided by Peter Cordes](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYhBJAE5SAAdUBUJbBmc3Dz04hJsBX38gllDwqItMKyyGIQImYgIU908uYtKkiqqCHMCQsIjohUrq2rSG3tb2vILugEoLVFdiZHYOAFIAJgBmP2Q3LABqRdXHXvQxPGAGADoEPexFjQBBFfWGTdcdvYOCdCwqC6ub%2B7WNltMLt9ngWCw/ARiH4fqtrnc/sdTkwFBAuMsABwTbbIBBVbYKObBVxURYAVgAQlwNMtJAAqam0umrZbkgAiII5iwA7FSeWy9hTEbQTsxUeisTi8cRtuhesTSZTGfTlczWWSBashQi7gA3VB4dDbQTGNgsZAxACeEH1hu2dLlBFI21tRrphPMBLwAC9MMYCNtMFQqJhrMYEr6Jn8edr7hpIiiWC6XEwbPQIH9tlns1mVssWKhdTmVmTyRSzVVMEx2c6SyXiExVLsyY4GHnswB6DvbBtNvYcx3bKrETM57N5gtF8fLUuUj2V6sa2sz%2BvIPsttvLZad7tzPurDkeofEEd3MfT5ZcEDN1vtrsEvoB1BUbYAd2hBGBtFQqBio/PE6FugACOTDbBoDIAGwZiuM57lMuywWSqjghoN6bqyZ7noh%2BZAaB2xcFBMGlnBa4IXWM4oSwXDoXm/5joBuogWByxERRZLwcuJHIeC27kreW70cWW6Tsx2yrGxSGcYh3FUastGCVhAEiXhYEqtB7HSexVGSApmG3NhOGifhZKSdxWlIVRZJ6UJF7GWBkFmauqjkZZ4KQTZSkMSpTH4dyTmkS5XEllR3KeQZ2F5soABK2AAGLYAAKo4AASASJQZGIBRxZHhYZUWxQlyVpRlBGsVwGlSbl/EYbZuY%2BYIIEySFqHOhBFXEfWjbYjVdFecJuG6o1wHNZR4INAR2W9j1G59RFymDcNo08SwyzOuVlXmd1eWRQ1Hwjdp4KrM6EkdZp229Yp83eYt%2B3LTpzrqZ1cEXbNV35XtTWHSwZLOqZZ1Sa9An6R9t1fW5LCQc6jkA1tLk7Qtk5Ld93LOv5sNdfDl0g7tyxMJ8OYACRZRVwUveuwN1Th%2BNGtmxNQWTOUU7V/U7tsn69G%2BH5fj%2BMQ4gI%2BBlFTebICwfPTrOFIODWy29np2H3mgYuVuzqCBgwRqEGEqYkMLW7aMEY5cIb2NUyAZvNuWmAsAu7I4SOW7bBAjrkXOcy2xq9vthAHqu1LGt23mDvbs7vQrFLwahgQ4Y%2BpgUas1m15B42ebLsse6pzhVEaJneZUVwudblRrJbmncmF8sOkV1Z1fubXLDchXyDIBXZokJaeZRlq0ZeaaLDhiGTyYBAXexvyPe3JC2w234I8xj3kT8DKEBT3g/ZoYK2xr/sqoVSCFJb%2BH4dRryC83JEJpmha1qOgqzoenfXq%2Bs%2BocEAqEyj2f3ICgi39/BwUxaCcDJLwTwHAtCkFQJwRwBIZhzGBA8HgpACCaAAVMAA1t0M4GIyRcDJGSVYGgNCSFWGSDQXBIjSCARwSQvAWASCIaQMBECoEcF4AoEAGhkGoKmHAWASAlYxDoGEcglBBHCPCMgYAXAWSkCwLqPA8wABqeBMCvgAPIxEYJwJBNBaCfmIBwiAwRUGkGCH4KolodG8HMcwYglp1HBG0FHaxpAlZsEEOohgtArHgN4FgYkwBHBiFoBw7g/jraGGAOIPxci8DECjngXUmAwkQMwKoUMrhPyuMhCUUxIpggNnsc4LApioRgmsVMKgBhgAKBUWozR2jwkyEECIMQ7ApAtPkEoNQpjdBrQMEYEAphjDmAKRwyAUxfxlDCQAWnUduWZVBlAAElsDbCWcMZA6DZkxGIKgT81gSCzN6PsowvBCxhGhFgCZI9GiJLsBABwAx6ikB8H4Do%2BQugNAyIkAQLz0jxD%2BQwUYnRwhDBKA88oj4AUQqaAIFo1RQVfPBRYGFLg6h6GGEij5YxvlTAUHA%2BYEhAHANAaY1h2xVAYkgrMyCulgDNwIqsM4IdcCEBIIhVYXAJi8BQX4j%2BpBMFkLOFIDEkhJCQUiJEMk9LIgYgGZwWhTCKWcHYZw7hArSUcGWHQhhXDmEXLVZqrQgrkmGKSBEIAA)

- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5218 CPU with 22MiB LLC
- OS: CentOS7 with kernel 5.14.0
- compiler: gcc 4.8.5 and gcc 11.2.1
- compile option: `gcc nt_memcpy.c -o nt_memcpy.exe -O2 -msse2 -mavx -std=gnu99`
- tool used for bandwidth monitor: `pcm-memory`

Result, with array sizes of 32MB and 1GB, calling the copy function in a loop.

- When copying 32MB of data, I have 4284.13 MB/s reads and 3778.02 MB/s writes.  (The CPU has 22 MiB of L3 cache, so this test size is too small to be a good test on this CPU, unlike Peter's i7-6700k with 8 MiB, where it was almost large enough.)
- When copying 1GB of data, I have 6336.48 MB/s reads and 3803.00 MB/s writes
- A baseline near-idle is 100 MB/s read, 75 MB/s write

This result does not meet the expected behavior of the non-temporal store instruction (expected read and write bandwidth should be close).

It is also different from the results obtained by Peter Cordes
(see comments for details)

> I can't repro your results on an i7-6700k with DDR4-2666. **Read ~= write bandwidth** as monitored by intel_gpu_top to get stats from the integrated memory controllers. (About 13400 MiB/s read, 13900 MiB/s write, vs. a baseline near-idle of 1200 MiB/s read, 8 to 16 MiB/s write.)

> Raising the array sizes to 1GiB, **my IMC read bandwidth is just idle + write bandwidth**, so no excess reads.

Where may the additional memory read bandwidth in my experiment come from?

---

The following are the pmc collected by perf, and no significant rfo events were observed. It seems that nt-store has taken effect.

```
# taskset -c 1 ./perf5 stat --all-user -e task-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,idq.mite_uops,offcore_requests.demand_rfo,l2_rqsts.all_rfo -- ./nt_memcpy.exe

 Performance counter stats for './nt_memcpy.exe':

     88,537.13 msec task-clock                #    1.000 CPUs utilized
             0      context-switches          #    0.000 /sec
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 /sec
       278,571      page-faults               #    3.146 K/sec
239,435,668,714      cycles                    #    2.704 GHz                      (93.56%)
55,340,543,407      instructions              #    0.23  insn per cycle           (94.51%)
53,026,607,051      uops_issued.any           #  598.919 M/sec                    (93.92%)
15,151,551,517      idq.mite_uops             #  171.132 M/sec                    (93.56%)
           168      offcore_requests.demand_rfo #    1.898 /sec                     (93.75%)
           994      l2_rqsts.all_rfo          #   11.227 /sec                     (92.61%)

  88.541352219 seconds time elapsed

  85.776548000 seconds user
   2.557275000 seconds sys
```

---

update:

I conducted an experiment with a client CPU:

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU with 16MiB LLC
- OS: Ubunt with kernel 5.15.0
- compiler: gcc 9.4.0
- compile option: `gcc nt_memcpy.c -o nt_memcpy.exe -O2 -msse2 -mavx -std=gnu99`
- tool used for bandwidth monitor: `intel-gpu-top`

Result, with array sizes of 1GB, calling the copy function in a loop.

- When copying 1GB of data, I have 14260 MiB/s reads and 14133 MiB/s writes
- A baseline near-idle is 48 MB/s read, 4 MB/s write

This result is in line with expectations and also in line with the data obtained by Peter.

**Is it the difference in server and client CPUs, or is it the difference in tools between `pcm-memory` and `intel-gpu-top`? I am unable to use `intel-gpu-top` on the server (because I do not have a graphics card), and cannot use `pcm-memory` on the client CPU (architecture not supported), so I cannot verify each other.**

Comment: What CPU are you testing on?  Are your buffers aligned by 64, so all the NT stores are to a single pair of cache lines before doing any loads that might need LFBs (and thus might evict an LFB, resulting in a partial-line write)?  Also, that prefetch distance is way too short.  The first prefetch is the same address your very next load will use next iteration.  But that doesn't explain the problem; load-hit-prefetch is probably fine. (Unless promoting the NT prefetch to a normal demand load results in an extra off-core request...)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm using Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5218 CPU. Both source and destination address is 64 Byte aligned.

Comment: I can't repro your results on an i7-6700k with DDR4-2666.  Read ~= write bandwidth as monitored by `intel_gpu_top` to get stats from the integrated memory controllers.  (About 13400 MiB/s read, 13900 MiB/s write, vs. a baseline near-idle of 1200 MiB/s read, 8 to 16 MiB/s write.)  https://godbolt.org/z/4xr8qha9P was the full program I ran, copying global arrays from `alignas(128) char srcbuf[1024*1024*32] = {1};` to `alignas(128) char dstbuf[1024*1024*32];`, calling it in a loop.  (The non-zero array initializer puts it in `.data`.  32 MiB is 4x larger than L3 cache, amortizing page faults.)

Comment: I tried your code and got different results. I have 22MB of L3 cache space on my device. I copied data sizes of 32MB and 1GB respectively, and obtained bandwidth through the pcm-memory: 1) When copying 32MB of data, I have 4284.13 MB/s reads and 3778.02 MB/s writes; 2) When copying 1GB of data, I have 6336.48 MB/s reads and 3803.00 MB/s writes.  A baseline near-idle of 100 MB/s read, 75 MB/s write.

Comment: I also tested the dTLB-load-misses,dTLB-loads,dTLB-store-misses,dTLB-stores events with perf. The tlb miss rate has not changed, so the read bandwidth is not generated by page walk.

Comment: I compile this code with: gcc -O2 -msse2 nt_memcpy.c -o nt_memcpy.exe -mavx -std=gnu99. My gcc version is 4.8.5. Is it possible that the compiler version is too old?

Comment: Raising the array sizes to 1GiB, my IMC read bandwidth is just idle + write bandwidth, so no excess reads.  With 32MiB arrays I was likely getting some L3 cache hits (from the adaptive replacement policy), and 1GiB regions makes that go away.  (IMC bandwidth:  read ~14550 MiB, write ~13100 MiB/s.)

Comment: The code should be spending all its time inside the hand-written asm loop, so a different compiler version would change nothing.  Assembler + linker versions could possibly matter for defaults on section layout or something, but it's hard to imagine any difference there possibly mattering.  4K aliasing or not shouldn't create extra read bandwidth.

Comment: Skylake-server has the same cores as Skylake-client (except SKL-client has AVX-512 disabled), but the uncore is different, including higher latency (in general, including for handing off NT stores so the core can stop tracking them, see   [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43343231)).  This could perhaps affect LFB allocation which could *perhaps* explain some of this.  Or maybe it's other hardware differences.  This is also part of why per-core bandwidth is so much worse in Skylake-server than client, like 3.5x in this case.

Comment: [edit] your question with your detailed test results.  I had downvoted because of a lack of [mcve] and details of the test setup and results, and can't change my vote until the question is edited. (And those details belong in the question anyway, especially since there's a bounty on it.)

Comment: I don't suppose kernel differences could matter, like transparent hugepages for the destination array?  I'm on 6.5.3-arch1-1.  (And BTW, my system uses the iGPU, that's why I'm able to use `intel_gpu_top` to read the IMC bandwidth stats, and probably part of why my idle read bandwidth is 1250 MiB/s.  With the the screen blanked (`xset dpms force off`), idle B/W drops to 130 MiB/s read.)

Comment: Anyway, an ancient GCC version like 4.8.5 probably doesn't matter for this experiment, but I'd serious question why you're not using a more modern GCC on a system where you care about performance.  Presumably the rest of the system is also pretty outdated.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and help. I have edited the question and provided further explanation on current experiment result. I will try doing some experiments on the client CPU (if I can find one). Regarding the issue of why my gcc version is so low. I am also very helpless about this. I have reported to the person in charge of server operations (also my senior) many times, but there are no plans to upgrade.

Comment: Oh, that sucks if you don't have control over the software installed on the server.  But at least it has a kernel that's not also ancient, so you can run `perf`.  Do you get counts for RFOs, like `l2_rqsts.all_rfo` or `offcore_requests.demand_rfo`?  If NT stores were working properly, those counts should be very low.  I get `241` and `99` respectively while I left this running for about 125 seconds. `taskset -c 1 perf stat --all-user -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,idq.mite_uops,offcore_requests.demand_rfo,l2_rqsts.all_rfo`

Comment: This is the worst part of the whole thing. The perf on my server cannot recognize these events. This is my question regarding this matter（ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77306095/how-to-count-offcore-pmu-events-on-an-old-kernel ）

Comment: I get 994 and 168 respectively with 1GB array size and 300 iteration. And it takes 88.54 seconds.

Comment: Ok, so you're getting negligible demand-RFOs, so that doesn't explain the extra read bandwidth.  But maybe partial-line NT stores wouldn't generate RFOs from the core, maybe RMW cycles inside the memory controller?  I don't know `pcm-memory`; are we sure it's trustworthy?  And does it measure true memory controller DRAM bandwidth?

Comment: pcm-memory is part of the official tool provided by Intel (https://github.com/intel/pcm). Accoring to Intel, bandwidth is collected by the following function: `Memory bw（GB/s） = （UNC_M_CAS_COUNT.RD +UNC_M_CAS_COUNT.WR） * 64 / 1000000000`. So the read and write bandwidth may correspond to these two events separately

Comment: If `perf` can use the same events `pcm-memory` is using, that might be one way to check things, e.g. `perf stat -e ... -e unc_arb_trk_requests.data_read,unc_arb_trk_requests.writes` if those are the same events as `UNC_M_CAS_COUNT.RD` / WR.

Comment: I tried that on my system; I don't think `unc_arb_trk_requests.data_read` or write is the same event, since I think the counts look too low.  (It can only be measured with `perf -a` system-wide.)